# Promise create custom fail is not a function Angularjs error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

As i am trying to use promise to create html5 directory functions in angularjs.
but it shows error as promise not defined.

Angular file:-

```
$scope.createDirectory = function(dirName,dirLocation){
        fileManager.createDirectory(dirName,dirLocation)
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data, "dir created");
        }).fail(function(err){
            console.log(err,"dir err while creating");
        });
    };
```

JS File:-

```
var fileManager = {
createDirectory: function(directoryName,dirLocation){
                    var makePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                        dirLocation.getDirectory(directoryName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(data){
                            resolve(data);
                        }, function(error){
                            reject(error);
                        });
                    });
                    return makePromise;
                }
}

TypeError: fileManager.createDirectory(...).then(...).fail is not a function
at h.$scope.createDirectory (app.js:60)
at angular.min.js:196
at f (angular.min.js:224)
at h.$eval (angular.min.js:123)
at h.$apply (angular.min.js:123)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:224)
at HTMLButtonElement.c (angular.min.js:32)
```

how to create promise properly and bind it to angular function.
I've used catch instead of fail it worked. how to create custom error callback to all fail function like [this](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/working-offline/jsonstore/jsonstore-javascript-api/)

Comment: `new promise` ? It is a typo, It must be `new Promise`. `Promise` => `P` must be in capital...

Comment: ok it was a typo. Now how to catch the fail callback function. it causing error.

Answer (score 5):

There is typo in `promise`, It should be `new Promise`. Though I would suggest you to use `$q` instead of `Promise`.

The advantage of using `$q` instead of `Promise` object is, you code will be angular context & you don't need to care to run digest cycle manually. Where as if you use `Promise` then you need to run digest cycle manually(as `Promise` would be native asynchronous JS function, considered to be outside world of angular).

```
createDirectory: function(directoryName, dirLocation) {
    var makePromise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        dirLocation.getDirectory(directoryName, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, function(data) {
            resolve(data);
        }, function(error) {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
    return makePromise;
};
```

**Update**

`.fail` function isn't available on `$q` object, you need to change your `fileManager.createDirectory` function code call to below.

```
$scope.createDirectory = function(dirName,dirLocation){
    fileManager.createDirectory(dirName,dirLocation)
    .then(function(data){ //success callback
        console.log(data, "dir created");
    }, function(err){ //error callback
        console.log(err,"dir err while creating");
    });
};
```

Comment: If it is just a type...We have a __a simple typographical error.__ flag for that..

Comment: @RayonDabre do look at my updated answer..other than that we need to care about running digest cycle if we use `Promise`..

Comment: Agreed... Even though OP is not facing the issue right now.. He will be having it soon with `Promise`..

Comment: @PankajParkar how to clear fail error as a function or how to catch errorcallback

Comment: @SathyaRaj You wrong syntax of `.fail`, do look at my updated answer

Comment: @PankajParkar if u use catch instead of fail it will work . how to create a custom function instead of catch function .like this https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/working-offline/jsonstore/jsonstore-javascript-api/

Comment: @SathyaRaj my friend.. I told you to use `$q`, & `$q` doesn't have `.fail` method.. It is there for `Promise` object