# Angular2 - Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in nested call

Tags: angular, asynchronous, callback, observable, chaining

I have looked at a number of resources including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341619/cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined-in-nested-calls-in-angular-2), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712659/angular-2-two-backend-service-calls-on-success-of-first-service/36712707#36712707) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173649/angular2-how-to-chain-async-service-calls-http-requests-in-a-component), but I have not been able to achieve the desired result.

All I'm trying to do is authenticate a user (using firebase) and then once authenticated, load up their profile and store it in a variable `userProfile` before loading up the next page Dashboard:

My Signin service:

```
public signinUser(user: User) {
    this.af.auth.login({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    },
        {
            provider: AuthProviders.Password,
            method: AuthMethods.Password
        }

    )
        .then(                
        success => {
            console.log('Authenticated');
            this.getProfile().subscribe( // PROBLEM is here
                profile => {
                    console.log(profile);
                    console.log('Profile Loaded');
                    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                }
            )               
        }
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
            ...
            console.log('ERROR SIGNING USER IN');
        }
```

My `getProfile()` method:

```
public getProfile(): Observable<any> {            
        return this.af.database.object('/profiles/' + this.user.uid)
        .flatMap(
            profile => {
                console.log('inside success');
                console.log(profile);
                this.userProfile = <User>profile;                    
                console.log('getProfile has completed');       
                return profile;
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
```

This is how part of the log looks:

```
Authenticated
auth.service.ts:104 ERROR SIGNING USER IN
auth.service.ts:105 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at auth.service.ts:91
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:232)
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:238)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:231)
at Zone.run (zone.js:114)
at zone.js:502
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:229)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:154)
auth.service.ts:106 Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
auth.service.ts:184 inside success
auth.service.ts:185 Object {confirmPassword: "123123", email: "aaa@gmail.com2", github: "aaa" name: "a", password: "123123"…}
auth.service.ts:188 
getProfile has completed()
auth.service.ts:185
```

I can see that the methods, individually are working as intended. The user authenticates, and the profile is loaded (shown in log). The problem lies with the subscribe event for reasons which I do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this is strange but I restarted webpack and it seems to have cured the problem.

This is how the code looks and it is correctly authenticating via the promise, and then on success it loads the profile which then loads the next page:

My `signinUser` method:

```
public signinUser(user: User) {
    this.af.auth.login({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    },
        {
            provider: AuthProviders.Password,
            method: AuthMethods.Password
        }

    )
        .then(                
        success => {
            console.log('Authenticated');
            this.getProfile().subscribe(
                profile => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                }, 
                error => console.log(error)
            )
```

And my `getProfile` method:

```
public getProfile(): Observable<User> {        
        return this.af.database.object('/profiles/' + this.user.uid)
        .map(                
            profile => {
                console.log('inside success');
                console.log(profile);
                this.userProfile = <User>profile;                    
                console.log(this.userProfile);        
                return profile;
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
}
```

> The callstack:
>
> 1. User is authenticated
> 2. Subscribe to getProfile and wait for method to finish...
>
>    1. GetProfile() method executes
>    2. Profile is set
> 3. Page is redirected

Comment: "I restarted webpack and it seems to have cured the problem" - it helps me (Angular 5)

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that `getProfile` doesn't really return an `Observable`.

You use `flatMap` so you can chain the observable sequence and return the profile as an observable. But in order for this to work, your callback inside the `flatMap` should return a promise or an observable (as I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748241/how-to-do-the-chain-sequence-in-rxjs/37748799#37748799)). Otherwise the chain of observables is broken.

So what you probably need to do is something like:

```
public getProfile(): Observable<any> {            
        return this.af.database.object('/profiles/' + this.user.uid)
        .flatMap(
            profile => {
                console.log('inside success');
                console.log(profile);
                this.userProfile = <User>profile;                    
                console.log('getProfile has completed');       
                return Promise.resolve(profile);//<-- this is what needs to be changed
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up making some minor alternations and restarting `webpack` and it strangely solved my problem.

That was also my thought that the chained sequence was not returning an observable, hence the error. +1 as a thank you and I think it will be a useful answer to another!